# Get Visual Studio Designer's (Cider) zoom level

Tags: visual-studio

I am developing a smart tag for one of my WPF controls. The smart tag is added through an AdornerProvider in the design dlls of the control. What I want to do is to synchronize the zoom level of my smart tag and the Visual Studio designer, because if I zoom in/out the Visual Studio designer, the smart tag remains unchanged. Anyone got an idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

private DesignerView Designer
        {
            get
            {
                return DesignerView.FromContext(this.Context);
            }
        }

```
    protected override void Activate(ModelItem item)
    {
        this.adornedControlModel = item;
        Designer.ZoomLevelChanged += new EventHandler(Designer_ZoomLevelChanged);
        //
        // YOUR CODE
        //
        base.Activate(item);
    }

    void Designer_ZoomLevelChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
```